# Angular JS - Ng-Repeat providing li's but not data inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code usage of ng-repeat, I am getting 3 blank `<li/>` but not data within of 3 populations. Can someone help why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in Cities">{{population}}</li>
</ul>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.Cities = [{population:'10,200'},{population:'20,000'},{population:'30,000'}];
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in Cities">{{x.population}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in Cities">{{x.population}}</li>
    </ul>
  <script>

  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
     $scope.Cities = [{population:'10,200'},{population:'20,000'},{population:'30,000'}];
  });
  </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

You just forgot (x.population) otherwise it was OK.